# Inputting functions in a equation

Tags: functions

If $f(x) = x^2- 1$ and $g(x) = 2 – 4x $

The equation is $g(g(x))$... Do I input it like $g(2-4x),$
so that it comes to $2(2-4x)$?

Or am I wrong on that?

I also have $(f+g)(-2)$ and I know that is $f(-2)+g(2)$ but I'm a little stuck there. Any guidance would help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Following TheSilverDoe's answer, if $g(x) = (2 - 4x) = y$ then $g[g(x)] = g(y) = (2 - 4y) = 2 - \{4 \times [2 - 4x]\}.$

Answer (score 1):

$$g(g(x))=g(2-4x)=2-4(2-4x)=16x-6$$

and
$$(f+g)(-2)=f(-2)+g(-2)=(-2)^2-1+2-4(-2)=13$$